# Angular Directive Load Order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning directives from Thinkster, when I actually load the index.html, and hover over "Say Something", in the console i get:

["howdy", "hi", "hello"]---

I'm expecting ["hello", "howdy", "hi"]--- assuming the directives get evaluated from left to right, so first hello gets pushed into $scope.words, then howdy, then hi, but that clearly is not what happens here, what does actually go on beneath the hood?

Angular Code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

angular.module('greetings', [])

.directive("welcome", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.words = [];

      this.sayHello = function() {
        $scope.words.push("hello");
      };

      this.sayHowdy = function() {
        $scope.words.push("howdy");
      };

      this.sayHi = function() {
        $scope.words.push("hi");
      };
    },

    link: function(scope, element){
      element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
        console.log(scope.words);
      });
    }
  }
})

.directive("hello", function() {
  return {
    require: "welcome",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, welcomeCtrl) {
      welcomeCtrl.sayHello();
    }
  };
})

.directive("howdy", function() {
  return {
    require: "welcome",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, welcomeCtrl) {
      welcomeCtrl.sayHowdy();
    }
  };
})

.directive("hi", function() {
  return {
    require: "welcome",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, welcomeCtrl) {
      welcomeCtrl.sayHi();
    }
  };
});



})();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Egghead Directive</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="greetings">
  <welcome hello howdy hi>Say something!</welcome>
  <!-- Javascripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think directive order evaluation on the element is not well-defined. In the JS, the directives are being defined in a certain order, but the actual calls might not be. I would find the actual DOM version of the HTML <welcome> interesting, since they might be being reordered there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directives have a field called 'priority' which sets the compile order. The default priority is 0 and it doesn't matter in which order you put them on the element.

```
.directive("hi", function() {
  return {
    require: "welcome",
    priority: 1,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, welcomeCtrl) {
      welcomeCtrl.sayHi();
    }
  };
});
```

The bigger the priority the earlier it will be compiled.

from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

> **priority**
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
> sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
> are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
> compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
> Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
> Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
> functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
> same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

**Update**

If the priorities are equal, the directives are compiled in alphabetical order, and then the link (post-link) functions are called in reverse.

Please refer to [this](http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/) for details.

Comment: if the default priority is 0, what decides that howdy is the first one that gets called?